# How to iterate over the first n elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, slice

Say I've got a list and I want to iterate over the first `n` of them.  What's the best way to write this in Python?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The normal way would be [slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
for item in your_list[:n]: 
    ...
```

Comment: Note that this creates a copy of the first `n` elements of the list, which may be slow and memory intensive for large lists. `itertools.islice` is far more efficient (and also works with any iterable).

Answer (score 42):

I'd probably use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) (<- follow the link for the docs), which has the benefits of:

- working with any iterable object
- not copying the list

Usage:

```
import itertools

n = 2
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for item in itertools.islice(mylist, n):
    print(item)
```

outputs:

```
1
2
```

One downside is that if you wanted a non-zero start, it has to iterate up to that point one by one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131550/895245

Tested in Python 3.8.6.

Comment: Note that when you have a list, it's usually simpler just to use slicing (unless you have to worry about memory usage issues or something like that). If this wasn't the *first* chunk but if it was some later chunk, normal slicing can be faster as well as nicer-looking.

Comment: Fair enough. Plus regular slicing is more concise, which the OP apparently cares about...

Answer (score 13):

You can just slice the list:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> n = 3
>>> l[:n]
[1, 2, 3]
```

and then iterate on the slice as with any iterable.

Answer (score 2):

Python lists are O(1) random access, so just:

```
for i in xrange(n):
    print list[i]
```

Comment: Tinkering with indices is usually something worth striving to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, slicing is better; I didn't think of it