# Skip first entry in for loop in python?

Tags: python

In python, How do I do something like:

```
for car in cars:
   # Skip first and last, do work for rest
```

Comment: i'm a newbie, but i have been using `for n, i in enumerate(cars): if n!= 0: do something to i`.  the logic is that it adds a 'counter' to each value which you can then target eg with `if n == some_value`.  in this example it would do something to each instance of i, except for the first one.

Answer (score 533, accepted):

To skip the first element in Python you can simply write

```
for car in cars[1:]:
    # Do What Ever you want
```

or to skip the last elem

```
for car in cars[:-1]:
    # Do What Ever you want
```

You can use this concept for any [`sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) (not for any [`iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) though).

Comment: Not for all [iterables](http://docs.python.org//glossary.html#term-iterable), but for all [sequences](http://docs.python.org//glossary.html#term-sequence).

Comment: How about memory usage? Does slice make a new copy of sub-sequence?

Comment: @Voyager Yes, It does  make new copy.

Comment: Remember that [it's a shallow, not deep, copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131563/183120) i.e. the new sublist itself and references inside are copies, not the contained objects themselves.

Answer (score 333):

The other answers only work for a sequence.

For any iterable, to skip the first item:

```
itercars = iter(cars)
next(itercars)
for car in itercars:
    # do work
```

If you want to skip the last, you could do:

```
itercars = iter(cars)
# add 'next(itercars)' here if you also want to skip the first
prev = next(itercars)
for car in itercars:
    # do work on 'prev' not 'car'
    # at end of loop:
    prev = car
# now you can do whatever you want to do to the last one on 'prev'
```

Comment: Also see [Sven Marnach](http://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10079869/500584)

Comment: I found that doing cars.pop(0) and cars.pop() works well.

Comment: @dreamwork801 My answer and Sven's, which I link in the first comment, work for any iterable, even infinite ones, as they don't require an O(n) operation on the data before iteration begins. Your suggestion, and Abhjit's, both only work for sequences, not any iterable.

Answer (score 54):

The best way to skip the first item(s) is:

```
from itertools import islice
for car in islice(cars, 1, None):
    pass
    # do something
```

[`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) in this case is invoked with a start-point of `1`, and an end point of `None`, signifying the end of the [`iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

To be able to skip items from the end of an `iterable`, you need to know its length (always possible for a list, but not necessarily for everything you can iterate on). for example, `islice(cars, 1, len(cars)-1)` will skip the first and last items in `cars`.

Comment: Take a look at Sven's (underappreciated) answer. He covers skipping an arbitrary number of items at the beginning and / or end of any iterable using `islice` quite well, without knowing the length or storing more items in memory at once than absolutely necessary.

Comment: Sven's answer will actually store the entire iterator in memory - collections.deque will run through the iterator. Try doing something like collections.deque(xrange(10000000)). There's no need to store all the ints in memory if you want to skip the first item...

Comment: An `islice` is what is passed to the `deque`, not the whole iterator, and it is only the length of the number of items to skip at the end. It doesn't store the whole iterator in memory.

Answer (score 31):

Here is a more general generator function that skips any number of items from the beginning and end of an iterable:

```
def skip(iterable, at_start=0, at_end=0):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for x in itertools.islice(it, at_start):
        pass
    queue = collections.deque(itertools.islice(it, at_end))
    for x in it:
        queue.append(x)
        yield queue.popleft()
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(skip(range(10), at_start=2, at_end=2))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Might want to add a fast path for `at_end == 0`.

Comment: collections.deque(...) will immediately go through the iterator. This means skip(xrange(10000000), 1) will take up a lot of memory even though it really shouldn't.

Comment: @RoeeShenberg: `skip(xrange(10000000), 1)` will use `at_end=0`, so the parameter to `deque()` will be `islice(it, 0)`, which will only consume zero elements of `it`.  This won't take up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 16):

This code skips the first and the last element of the list:

```
for item in list_name[1:-1]:
    #...do whatever
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: the OP only wants to skip the first element. why :-1 ?

Comment: It's not actually _reserved_; the name `list` can be re-bound. That's why you _shouldn't_, rather than _can't_, use it.

Comment: @luke14free, the question says skip first element, but his code comment implies that he really wants to skip first and last.

Comment: @luke14free that's what the title says, not what he typed inside the code: "skip if first or last"

Comment: okay it was just for curiosity.. I honestly don't even know what programming language the OP is using

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
mylist=['one','two','three','four','five']
for i in mylist[1:]:
   print(i)
```

In python index start from 0, We can use  slicing operator to make manipulations in iteration.

```
for i in range(1,-1):
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my preferred choice. It doesn't require adding on much to the loop, and uses nothing but built in tools.

Go from:

```py
for item in my_items:
  do_something(item)
```

to:

```py
for i, item in enumerate(my_items):
  if i == 0:
    continue
  do_something(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, your syntax isn't really Python to begin with.

Iterations in Python are over he contents of containers (well, technically it's over iterators), with a syntax `for item in container`. In this case, the container is the `cars` list, but you want to skip the first and last elements, so that means `cars[1:-1]` (python lists are zero-based, negative numbers count from the end, and `:` is slicing syntax.

So you want

```
for c in cars[1:-1]:
    do something with c
```

Comment: This won't work with an iterable (e.g. a generator), only with a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @SvenMarnach 's Answer, but bit simpler and without using deque

```
>>> def skip(iterable, at_start=0, at_end=0):
    it = iter(iterable)
    it = itertools.islice(it, at_start, None)
    it, it1 = itertools.tee(it)
    it1 = itertools.islice(it1, at_end, None)
    return (next(it) for _ in it1)

>>> list(skip(range(10), at_start=2, at_end=2))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(skip(range(10), at_start=2, at_end=5))
[2, 3, 4]
```

Also Note, based on my `timeit` result, this is marginally faster than the deque solution

```
>>> iterable=xrange(1000)
>>> stmt1="""
def skip(iterable, at_start=0, at_end=0):
    it = iter(iterable)
    it = itertools.islice(it, at_start, None)
    it, it1 = itertools.tee(it)
    it1 = itertools.islice(it1, at_end, None)
    return (next(it) for _ in it1)
list(skip(iterable,2,2))
    """
>>> stmt2="""
def skip(iterable, at_start=0, at_end=0):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for x in itertools.islice(it, at_start):
        pass
    queue = collections.deque(itertools.islice(it, at_end))
    for x in it:
        queue.append(x)
        yield queue.popleft()
list(skip(iterable,2,2))
        """
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt = stmt1, setup='from __main__ import iterable, skip, itertools', number = 10000)
2.0313770640908047
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt = stmt2, setup='from __main__ import iterable, skip, itertools, collections', number = 10000)
2.9903135454296716
```

Comment: By using `tee()`, you're still creating an entire list in memory for the generator, right?  (your `it1`)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method:

```
for idx, car in enumerate(cars):
    # Skip first line.
    if not idx:
        continue
    # Skip last line.
    if idx + 1 == len(cars):
        continue
    # Real code here.
    print car
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project extends `itertools.islice` to handle negative indices.

Example

```
import more_itertools as mit

iterable = 'ABCDEFGH'
list(mit.islice_extended(iterable, 1, -1))
# Out: ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

Therefore, you can elegantly apply it slice elements between the first and last items of an iterable:

```
for car in mit.islice_extended(cars, 1, -1):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @maninthecomputer 's answer, when you need to skip the first iteration of a loop based on an int (`self._model.columnCount()` in my case):

```
for col in range(self._model.columnCount()):
    if col == 0:
        continue
```

Put more simply:

```
test_int = 3

for col in range(test_int):
    if col == 0:
        continue
    print(col)
```

Provides output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @user1063287's comment,
you can always do something like:

```py
        for i, car in enumerate(cars):
            if i == 0 or i == len(cars):
                pass
            else:
                print(car)
```

This would work for both lists and iterables.

Answer (score -1):

Good solution for support of `itertools.chain` is to use `itertools.islice` in order to take a slice of an iterable:

```
your_input_list = ['list', 'of', 'things']
for i, variant in list(itertools.islice(enumerate(some_function_that_will_output_itertools_chain(your_input_list)), 1, None)):
   """
   # No need for unnecessary conditions like this:
   if i == 0:
      continue
   """
   variant = list(variant) # (optional) converting back to list
   print(variant)
```

Comment: This does not appear to add any information that wasn't in existing answers.

Answer (score -3):

I do it like this, even though it looks like a hack it works every time:

```
ls_of_things = ['apple', 'car', 'truck', 'bike', 'banana']
first = 0
last = len(ls_of_things)
for items in ls_of_things:
    if first == 0
        first = first + 1
        pass
    elif first == last - 1:
        break
    else:
        do_stuff
        first = first + 1
        pass
```