# Python - Iteration over an unknown number of variables

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Say I have a list `range_list` which length is not know *a priori*. For example say `range_list = [2,5,4,10]`
I would like to iterate in the following manner:

```
for i in range(range_list[0]):
   for j in range(range_list[1]):
        for k in range(range_list[2]):
            for l in range(range_list[3]):
```

However since the length of `range_list` isn't fixed, I cannot nest a finite number of for loops like above.

I've tried using (unsuccessfully) the `zip` function in the following manner:

```
range_list_2
for i in range(len(range_list)):
        range_list_2.append(range(range_list[i]))

for i in zip(*range_list_2):
   print(i)
```

As a result I would be expecting

```
(0,0,0,0)
(1,0,0,0)
(0,1,0,0)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()`:

```
 |  product(*iterables, repeat=1) --> product object
 |
 |  Cartesian product of input iterables.  Equivalent to nested for-loops.
 |
 |  For example, product(A, B) returns the same as:  ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).
 |  The leftmost iterators are in the outermost for-loop, so the output tuples
 |  cycle in a manner similar to an odometer (with the rightmost element changing
 |  on every iteration).
```

For example:

```
from itertools import product

range_list = [2, 4, 3]
for i in product(*map(range, range_list)):
    print(i)
```

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 2)
(0, 3, 0)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 2)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Do you have an idea why using the `zip` function isn't working? I thought this was the kind of problem the `zip` function was used for.

Comment: @Meth `zip(*iterables) --> A zip object yielding tuples until an input is exhausted.`

`zip` creates tuples by pulling from each of the input iterators until one of them runs out. So if `range_list == [2,5,4,10]` your code first gets `0` from each of them and yields `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, then it gets a one from each of them and yields `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, and then the first one runs out so it's done.

Comment: A follow up question: is there a clean way to skip the `(0,0,0)` tuple ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079216/skip-first-entry-in-for-loop-in-python (I searched for python iterator skip first). You can assign `product(...)` to a variable and call `next()` on it before looping on the rest of it.