# Best way to skip the first loop of a python for loop?

Tags: python

I'm currently using this code to skip the first loop of the for, is there a better way to do so ? (ui_queue[guild_id] is a dict)

```
remove_zero = 0
for x in ui_queue[guild_id]
    if remove_zero != 1:
        remove_zero = 1
        continue

    # stuff happening here
```

Comment: @khelwood, `ui_queue[guild_id]` is a dict not a list.

Comment: There are numerous answers in the [dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079265/3890632) describing ways to do this for any iterable object.