# Is there a way to omit the creation of the first file when using json.dump to generate multiple files?

Tags: python, json

I am unsing `json.dump` to generate multiple JSON files. The JSON is like this:

```
[
{"any": 2023},
{
"dia": 24,
"mes": 1,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 12,
"any_referencia": 2022,
"calendari_nom": "CTH"
}]
```

But what I need is that the first part, `{"any":2023}`, does not generate a JSON file.

I am using this code where `json_output` is the JSON script:

```
data = json.loads(json_output)

for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
    with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
        json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

Is there a way omit the creation of the first file before the creation of the file?

Comment: How do you know that `{"any": 2023}` specifically should be skipped? If it's purely the position: `data[1:]`? Should it be skipped in the numbering system, too (i.e. the first one is `_2`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip first entry in for loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079216/skip-first-entry-in-for-loop-in-python)

Comment: It must be skipped because the information in the that part is irrelevant to us. Because the format of the JSON, is always on the first position.  In this moment is {any:2023}, maybe next year will be {any:2024}.  But always at the firt position. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always the first item, you can check for that in the loop, i.e.

```
for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
    if i == 1:
        continue
    ...
```

or just skip the first item altogether by slicing `data`:

```
for i, d in enumerate(data[1:], 1):
    ...
```

Alternately, if you want to skip any item that only has a single `any` key:

```
for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
    if set(d) == {'any'}:
        continue
    ...
```

Finally, if you want to be able to skip items and not have gaps in the numbering series, you can use a separate `itertools.count` for numbering them:

```
counter = itertools.count(1)
for d in data:
    if "foo" in d:  # skip this
        continue
    if not d:  # skip an empty entry
        continue
    # (etc...)
    i = next(counter)
    with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
        json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX, just a moment  before I have resolvet it. But your other options are interesting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with an If clause, like this:

```
import json

    data = json.loads(json_output)
    
    for i, d in enumerate(data, 0):
        if i==0:
            None
        else:
            with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
                json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

In this way, the first part is not generated.

Thanks