# Performance of my function removing keys from a dictionary which are substrings of other keys

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, dictionary

I am curious why removing a line in my code results in a significant increase in performance. The function itself takes a dictionary and removes all keys which are substrings of other keys.

The line which slows my code down is:

```
if sub in reduced_dict and sub2 in reduced_dict:
```

Here's my function:

```
def reduced(dictionary):
    reduced_dict = dictionary.copy()
    len_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key in dictionary:
        len_dict[len(key)].append(key)
    start_time = time.time()
    for key, subs in len_dict.items():
        for key2, subs2 in len_dict.items():
            if key2 > key:
                for sub in subs:
                    for sub2 in subs2:
                        if sub in reduced_dict and sub2 in reduced_dict: # Removing this line gives a significant performance boost
                            if sub in sub2:
                                reduced_dict.pop(sub, 0)
    print time.time() - start_time
    return reduced_dict
```

The function checks if sub is in sub2 many times. I assumed that if I checked for this comparison having already been made, I would be saving myself time. This doesn't seem to be the case. Why is the constant time function for lookup in a dictionary slowing me down?

I am a beginner so, I'm interested in concepts.

When I tested if the line in question is ever returning False, it appears that it is. I've tested this with the following

```
def reduced(dictionary):
    reduced_dict = dictionary.copy()
    len_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key in dictionary:
        len_dict[len(key)].append(key)
    start_time = time.time()
    for key, subs in len_dict.items():
        for key2, subs2 in len_dict.items():
            if key2 > key:
                for sub in subs:
                    for sub2 in subs2:
                        if sub not in reduced_dict or sub2 not in reduced_dict:
                            print 'not present' # This line prints many thousands of times
                        if sub in sub2:
                            reduced_dict.pop(sub, 0)
    print time.time() - start_time
    return reduced_dict
```

For 14,805 keys in the function's input dictionary:

- 19.6360001564 sec. without the line
- 33.1449999809 sec. with the line

Here are 3 dictionary examples. [Biggest sample dictionary with 14805 keys](http://justpaste.it/14805keys), [medium sample dictionary](http://justpaste.it/festival_dict) and [smaller sample dictionary](http://justpaste.it/ATGC)

I have graphed time in seconds (Y) vs input size in # of keys (X) for the first 14,000 keys in the biggest example dictionary. It appears all these functions have exponential complexity.

- John Zwinck [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25819689/3761932) for this question
- Matt my algorithm for this question without the dictionary
  comparision
- [Matt exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421289/remove-a-dictionary-key-if-it-is-a-substring-in-any-other-key) is from my first attempt at this problem. This took 76s
- Matt compare is the algorithm in this question with the dict comparison line
- tdelaney [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25819595/3761932) for this question. Algorithm 1 & 2 in order
- georg [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25422647/3761932) from a related question I asked

[image]

**The accepted answer executes in apparently linear time.**

[image: Marcelo Cantos]

I'm surprised to find magic ratio exists for input size where run time for a dict look-up == a string search.

Comment: Can you include the sample dicts you're using to test this? Also, using `time.time()` to measure this isn't usually sufficiently accurate. You should use the `timeit` module instead.

Comment: Here are 2 dictionary examples. The first is longer http://justpaste.it/festival_dict and the second is shorter http://justpaste.it/ATGC

Comment: Your code is probably slow more due to the quadruple-nested "for" loops than anything else.  :)

Comment: @John Zwinck The above code runs much faster than a solution in a previous question of mine while trying to solve the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25422647/3761932 I will try to tackle the nesting but that's another question.

Comment: You describe an algorithm that operates on the keys, but your code operates on the values. Is that just a typo?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos The keys which are being examined as substrings are from the input dictionary called 'dictionary'. These keys are then inserted as values into another dictionary called len_dict. The purpose of len_dict is to put all keys together which have the same length. This way I will only search for keys which are substrings in other keys with a greater length.

Comment: @mattkaeo: Indeed. I should read more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sample corpus, or any corpus in which most keys are small, it's much faster to test all possible subkeys:

```
def reduced(dictionary):
    keys = set(dictionary.iterkeys())
    subkeys = set()
    for key in keys:
        for n in range(1, len(key)):
            for i in range(len(key) + 1 - n):
               subkey = key[i:i+n]
               if subkey in keys:
                   subkeys.add(subkey)

    return {k: v
            for (k, v) in dictionary.iteritems()
            if k not in subkeys}
```

This takes about 0.2s on my system (i7-3720QM 2.6GHz).

Comment: This is the fastest algorithm. I'm graphing it over 103,000 keys. I'll add this graph to the question. There appears to be a magic ratio for input size where a dict look-up == a string search.

Answer (score 1):

You create len_dict, but even though it groups keys of equal size, you still have to traverse everything multiple times to compare. Your basic plan is right - sort by size and only compare what's the same size or bigger, but there are other ways to do that. Below, I just created a regular list sorted by key size and then iterated backwards so that I could trim the dict as I went. I'm curious how its execution time compares to yours. It did your little dict example in .049 seconds.

(I hope it actually worked!)

```
def myfilter(d):
    items = d.items()
    items.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
    for i in range(len(items)-2,-1,-1):
        k = items[i][0]
        for k_fwd,v_fwd in items[i+1:]:
            if k in k_fwd:
                del items[i]
                break
    return dict(items)
```

**EDIT**

A significant speed increase by not unpacking k_fwd,v_fwd (after running both a few times, this wasn't really a speed-up. something else must have been eating time on my PC for awhile).

```
def myfilter(d):
    items = d.items()
    items.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
    for i in range(len(items)-2,-1,-1):
        k = items[i][0]
        for kv_fwd in items[i+1:]:
            if k in kv_fwd[0]:
                del items[i]
                break
    return dict(items)
```

Comment: Your function is faster. For 14,805 keys, my function without the problematic line ran in 17.75 sec. Yours in 12.3139998913 sec. Your function returned 7087 keys & mine 7086, which is interesting. I like your approach. Do you have any insight why a dictionary lookup extended my function's runtime?

Comment: @mattkaeo dictionary lookups aren't *free*, they're just (pseudo) constant time.  You're doing millions of lookups due to how your code is structured.

Comment: 1. Your 2 for loops for len_dict.items() means that you rebuild items in that second loop len(len_dict) times, and throw most of them away in the if right after. the remaining dict lookups are fairly expensive compared to an indexed lookup on a list. In truth, I thought I'd beat you by a lot more than that. Now I'm puzzled...

Comment: @tdelaney That's interesting. I didn't know dictionary lookups could be more expensive than index lookups from a list. Here's the much larger 14805 key length dictionary I've been using for experimentation. http://justpaste.it/14805keys

Comment: @mattkaeo - that took 12.029 seconds on my machine. i'm doing a bit of tweaking...

Comment: oops, i read the results from a dict i generated w/ 22056 items. your 14805 set was 4.00 seconds. Interesting the increased time with the larger set - ain't exponential growth grand!

Comment: I had a bug in range() - it stopped at 1 not 0 so I returned one too many items. Also, I stopped unpacking k_fwd,v_fwd and had a big improvement to 4.34 seconds. editting the answer now.

Comment: @tdelaney Only 4 seconds? I'm curious why I'm not seeing a this same result. It appears your first algorithm ran faster for me. I wanted to see how each of these algorithms behaved as the input size increased. I've updated the question with a graph for my results.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a bit differently.  Here's a generator function which gives you the "good" keys only.  This avoids creating a dict which may be largely destroyed key-by-key.  I also have just two levels of "for" loops and some simple optimizations to try to find matches more quickly and avoid searching for impossible matches.

```
def reduced_keys(dictionary):
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    keys.sort(key=len, reverse=True) # longest first for max hit chance                                                                                                     
    for key1 in keys:
        found_in_key2 = False
        for key2 in keys:
            if len(key2) <= len(key1): # no more keys are long enough to match                                                                                              
                break
            if key1 in key2:
                found_in_key2 = True
                break
        if not found_in_key2:
            yield key1
```

If you want to make an actual dict using this, you can:

```
{ key: d[key] for key in reduced_keys(d) }
```

Comment: For my 14,805 key dictionary justpaste.it/14805keys yours = 27.7s with the same 7086 keys as my function. Mine = 17.7s. I'll try to time this in a different way. What is the most expensive part of your generator? Is it the length comparison or is it populating the dictionary?

Comment: Interesting. We could cache the length of key1 outside the inner loop. And this algorithm should be easy to port to C if you want much higher speed (yet still usable from Python). I'd be interested to know how fast it is if you sort in non-reverse order and take out the check for key lengths completely.