# Understanding slicing in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.7, slice

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10**5)

for i in xrange(x.size):
    foo(x[3000:40000])
```

and just another version of the code above

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10**5)
slice_of_x = x[3000:40000] 
for i in xrange(x.size):
    foo(slice_of_x)
```

Will the second code be faster or not? I am inclined to think in terms of pointer in C (so that infact the first may be faster) but I understand python is no C.

O.k. This post 
[Slicing a list in Python without generating a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy)
answers my question.

Comment: `Will the second code be faster or not?` You can use `timeit` and answer your question. https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: Yes I know, it tells me which one is faster. But it does not tell me how slicing works in python.

Comment: Amazing... OP **acknowledged** a duplicate, and nobody voted to close?

Answer (score 1):

Read this http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/#life-of-ndarray, in particular the section [Slicing with integers](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/#slicing-with-integers).

From the page [on slicing]

> Everything can be represented by changing only shape, strides, and possibly adjusting the data pointer!
>   Never makes copies of the data

So the overhead of creating a slice is small: constructing a Python object which stores a few tuples and a pointer to the data.

In your first code sample, you create the slice in the loop each time. In the second example you create the slice once. The difference will probably be negligible for most functions `foo` that you would choose to write.