# Does Python copy references to objects when slicing a list?

Tags: python, list, memory, copy, slice

When a list is sliced, are the references to its contents copied from the original list? I can imagine that this may not be necessary, but I read the opposite ([mentioned in passing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131563/42973)).

This question matters for instance for the following idiom, in the case of a very long `my_list`:

```
for (first_elmt, second_elmt) in itertools.izip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:]):
    …
```

A copy would use up both memory and, presumably, some time. I compared to looping over the index of `first_elmt` with `xrange()`, on a list of 100 million integers. The slicing approach is actually 20% faster, but does seem to copy references (the system time is longer). Is this indeed the case?

**PS**: I now realize that it is quite natural that slices copy the references: if the original list is modified, the slice does not change, so it is easier to have the implementation of the slice copy the references of the original list. A pointer to the CPython implementation would be interesting, though.

Comment: `does seem to copy data` - Nope, it will never do that. In fact, there will never be any copying of data unless you explicitly ask for it.

Comment: I agree. I meant "copy the references", as I was writing in the title and at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slicing will copy the references. If you have a list of 100 million things:

```
l = [object() for i in xrange(100000000)]
```

and you make a slice:

```
l2 = l[:-1]
```

`l2` will have its own backing array of 99,999,999 pointers, rather than sharing `l`'s array. However, the objects those pointers refer to are not copied:

```
>>> l2[0] is l[0]
True
```

If you want to iterate over overlapping pairs of elements of a list without making a copy, you can `zip` the list with an iterator that has been advanced one position:

```
second_items = iter(l)
next(second_items, None) # Avoid exception on empty input
for thing1, thing2 in itertools.izip(l, second_items):
    whatever()
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `zip` stops when any input iterator stops. This can be extended to cases where you're already working with an iterator using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
i1, i2 = itertools.tee(iterator)
next(i2, None)
for thing1, thing2 in itertools.izip(i1, i2):
    whatever()
```

Comment: Do you have a reference about the copy of the references? Now that I think of it, it makes sense to copy them just in case the original list is modified, though. Another point: instead of `next(…, None)`, I find it clearer to directly use `itertools.islice(…, 1, None)`, since it explicitly is a slice (and there is no need for an arbitrary default value like `None`, as in the case of `next()`).

Comment: @EOL: From the tutorial: "All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements. This means that the following slice returns a new (shallow) copy of the list: `>>> squares[:]`". You can also look at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a985b6455fde/Objects/listobject.c#l466).

Comment: Thanks! That's something I did not remember from reading the tutorial 10 years ago. :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, slicing DO copy references, in fact, it is an idiom to make copy of a list this way: `newlst = lst[:]`.

Comment: Good point. This is indeed yet another reason to expect that slices copy references (in addition to the fact that a slice does not change even if the original list does).