# Slicing a list without copying

Tags: python, list, slice

This is my first question on the forum and I'm also really new to Python, so maybe this doesn't make a lot of sense, but I'm just left wondering...

It's very related, but IMO this question [Slicing a list in Python without generating a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy) does not answer the question of how to slice a list in such a fashion that changing the slice would change the original?

Say, if I want to change only part of a list in a function and make sure that the function doesn't have access to all the members, how do I write this:

```
def myFunc(aList):
    for i in range(0,len(aList)):
        aList[i] = 0

wholeList = range(0,10)
partOfList = wholeList[3:6]
myFunc(partOfList)
```

so that the in the end `wholeList` would be

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

??

I guess this would work if the contents of `wholeList` were mutable objects, but with numbers is the only way to have the `myFunc` return the changed list and assign in the calling workspace?

Comment: Instead of typing `for i in range(0,len(aList)):  aList[i] = 0` in Python you can just type `for e in aList: e = 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify just a part of the list, you can send in only that slice, and assign the modifications to that same section using `return`:

```
def myFunc(aList):
    for i in range(0,len(aList)):
        aList[i] = 0
    return aList

wholeList = range(0,10)
wholeList[3:6] = myFunc(wholeList[3:6])
```

Otherwise as you said before, you are just creating new lists that happen to reference what is contained in the slice of the original, you'll have to reassign any modifications to the new list back into the old one.

To further clarify, the **elements** of `wholeList[3:6]` and `partOfList` are the same **objects**. But the lists are just references to those objects.  So `id(wholeList[3]) == id(partOfList[0])`, but if we change one of those references, eg `partOfList[0] = 10`, then we change the **reference** of `partOfList[0]` to `10` not the actual **object** (`3`) that was being pointed to.  Thus there is no action in this modification that would reflect any changes in `wholeList`, since it is still referencing the original object..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This concept of a list only containing references to actual objects is more or less clear to me... What I think I was really trying to ask is if it is possible to create a `partOfList` that would contain the same references as `wholeList`, but not all of them. Thus enabling to change only part of `wholeList` without an explicit assignment.  I guess the answer in short is "no".

Comment: @Juspe That's correct, they're just lists of references, modifying one element of a list will not reflect in any other lists **as long as those objects are immutable**.  If they are mutable objects, then they can be changed "through the slice" per say.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can modify the list directly:
>>> wholeList = range(0,10)
>>> wholeList[3:6] = [0 for _ in range(3)] # or = [0]*3
>>> wholeList
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Please add a brief explanation to the code, to make it a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

To offer an alternative, this works only in Python 2:

```
In [2]: a = range(10)
In [3]: a.__setslice__(3,6,[0]*3)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, I'd vote for the solutions other people gave because they are more readable. :))