# Does the : operator create copies of list references?

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

Let's say I do:

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>> b = a[:] 
>> a[0] = 0
>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

The statement `b = a[:]` clearly created a list `b` holding **copies** of the (potentially many) **references** that were also held by `a`. But the `=` operator only binds names and increase reference counts, so does the `:` operator **create copies** of **references** in Python? If so, when it comes to accessing lists, is that unique to the `:` operator? (e.g. indexing alone does not do that?)

Comment: No because the copying was already done by `a[:]`. The `=` did not do the copying, it just made `b` point to the new copy

Comment: All that an assignment does to give an object an additional name and increase the reference count of the object.

Comment: @rdas Thanks - I haven't been able to find any material indicating that slices create copies of references in Python (if you have any please let me know) but that would make sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slicing a list in Python without generating a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy)

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 - Yes it does. Sorry, I initially thought the assignment operator was doing the copying, and was then later reminded that it never copies anything (first comment from @rdas), which helped me find the questions that I included below and that you just linked above as well. TL;DR yes, that answers the question, so we can definitely mark this as a duplicate and close accordingly (I just voted for it). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the slice operator provides **copies** of the references, not **views**.  See e.g.

- [Why are slices in Python 3 still copies and not views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902235/why-are-slices-in-python-3-still-copies-and-not-views).
- [Slicing a list in Python without generating a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy)
- [Slicing a list without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274784/slicing-a-list-without-copying?noredirect=1&lq=1)