# Space Complexity of Python List Slices

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I'm having difficulty understanding the Space Complexity of Python List Slices.

For something like

```
arr[2:] = arr[2:][::-1]
```

is new space being allocated for the slice (like done in Strings since they are immutable) or is the operation done on the same array?

For something like:

`ans = [i+1 for i in range(n)]`

```
for i in range(k):
    ans[i:] = ans[i:][::-1]
```

What will be the space complexity? Will it be different or same than when ans is a string, something like `ans = '12345...n'`?

Comment: To answer your first question, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy).

Comment: assign the slice to a variable, check and compare `id(...)`s.

Comment: @Matos cool find, the "Short answer" to the other Q answers this one fully. Voting to close.

Comment: The linked question is not concerned with space complexity or inplace mutation at all. Vote for reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is strict about adhering to possible side effects. As far as the language is concerned, it is *incorrect* to perform any of your operations inplace.

Your operation

```
 arr[2:] = arr[2:][::-1]
```

are three separate slice operations:

- `arr[2:]` creates a new list from *all elements* (but the first two) of `arr`.
- `...[::-1]` creates a new, reversed list from *all elements* of `...`.
- `arr[2:] = ...` replaces *all elements* (but the first two) of `arr` with `...`.

Each slice operation basically amounts to a primitive O(n) copy operation. Since only references are copied, the size or type of elements does not matter.

In your complete example, that amounts to three O(n) slice operations in an O(k) loop:

```
ans = [i+1 for i in range(n)]   # O(n)
for i in range(k):              # O(k)
    ans[i:] = ans[i:][::-1]     # O(n)
```

In total, the time complexity amounts to O(nk). Space complexity is only O(n), since the temporary slices are reclaimable immediately. You basically end up with the initial list, plus some temporary copies.

---

> Will it be different or same than when `ans` is a string, something like `ans = '12345...n'`?

The complexity of the operations does not change - they are still the same primitive operations.

Practically, the CPython implementation cheats with certain objects. For example, `+=` is [inplace mutation for strings with refcount 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python#comment16292699_12171382) even though strings are immutable. However, this does not apply to your slice usage.

In general, relying on inbuilt optimisations is a bad idea with Python.

---

If you are worried about space, start with writing lean code. For example, `ans[i:][::-1]` should simply be `ans[i::-1]`. That alone halves the temporary space required.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, every list slicing operation involves making a copy of the relevant object references (*but not the objects themselves*).

In your example:

- `arr[2:]` makes a copy of the object references stored in `arr` starting at index 2, and places them into an unnamed new list (which I'll refer to as `L1`).
- `[::-1]` makes a copy of the object references in `L1` and places them, in reverse order, into an unnamed new list (which I'll refer to as `L2`).
- `arr[2:] = ...` replaces object references stored in `arr` with those stored in `L2`.

It's worth noting that none of this is guaranteed. This is just what CPython does currently.

Some relevant functions are:

- `list_slice` - simple slice (no stride)
- `list_subscript` - subscript, inc. extended slice (with stride)
- `list_ass_slice` - simple slice assignment (no stride)
- `list_ass_subscript` - subscript assignment, inc. using an extended slice

Take a look at the implementation of `list`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c

There are some fun tidbits to be found there, such as [code that protects against `a[::-1] = a`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2861).