# If slice copies references why this behavior?

Tags: python, list, reference, slice

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy), python copies references when slicing. I've tried the following:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=a[:]
>>> b[1]=0
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 0, 3]
>>> map(id,a)
[14508376, 14508352, 14508328]
>>> map(id,b)
[14508376, 14508400, 14508328]
```

Why does `b[1]=0` does not change `a[1]` (which should be the case if `b[1]` was indeed a reference to the same object, one might think)? Instead, it seems to generate a new reference/id and change the new object. Anywhere I can read up on this behavior in more detail?

Comment: Assignment copies references too. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: `b[1]=0` changes the reference, not the referred-to object.  So now the two lists have different references.  When you see changes reflected across lists, it's not because the change in a reference in `b` changes the reference in `a`, it's because the object that is referred to in both `a` and `b` had changed.  Draw some pictures with arrows representing the references, it really does help.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, but the behavior is different

Comment: Different from what? It's certainly not different from the behavior of copying references, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @user2357112 I meant `c=a` (assignment), `c[1]=0` result in `a` being `[1,0,3]`, unlike when using slice `a[:]`

Comment: @DeLorean88: Slicing copies the list and all the references inside it. `c=a` just copies the reference to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you start with `a = [1,2,3]`. In Python's data model, this means that `a` refers to an object in memory:

```
a -> [ * | * | * ]
       |   |   |
       v   v   v
       1   2   3
```

With `b = a`, you simply point another name at the same object:

```
a -> [ * | * | * ] <- b
       |   |   |
       v   v   v
       1   2   3
```

`b[1] = 0` changes the same reference `a[1] = 0` would:

```
           0
           ^
           |
a -> [ * | * | * ] <- b
       |       |
       v       v
       1   2   3
```

(The `2` is still in memory, possibly referenced directly or indirectly via some other name, but not via `a` or `b` anymore.)

---

With `b = a[:]`, you create a new *list*, but that new list contains references to the same object:

```
a -> [ * | * | * ]
       |   |   |
       v   v   v
       1   2   3
       ^   ^   ^
       |   |   |
b -> [ * | * | * ]
```

Now when you write `b[1] = 0`, you aren't changing `a[1]`, because `a` and `b` are distinct list objects.

```
a -> [ * | * | * ]
       |   |   |
       v   v   v
       1   2   3
       ^       ^
       |       |
b -> [ * | * | * ]
           |
           v
           0
```

Ned Batchelder's [blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) (and subsequent [PyCon talk](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)) is an excellent overview of Python's name model.