# How to deal with scope in a recursive python sort function

Tags: python, sorting, scope

I am implementing Stooge Sort in Python and I can't understand why my changes to the ordering of my array is not sticking. In other words, it appears that as I drill down recursively the cells are being swapped, but then after the function returns the ordering of my array is unchanged. Is it a scope issue, or some other pythonism I don't understand yet? Or is my algorithm incorrect?

```
import math

def StoogeSort(A):

    n = len(A)

    if (n == 2 and A[0] > A[1]):

        tmp = A[0]
        A[0] = A[1]
        A[1] = tmp 

    elif n > 2:

        m = int(math.ceil((2 * n) / 3)) 
        StoogeSort(A[0:m]) 
        StoogeSort(A[m-n:n]) 
        StoogeSort(A[0:m]) 

    return A


A = [4,2,1]
StoogeSort(A)
print "End:",A
A = [44,12,8,33,100]
StoogeSort(A)
print "End:",A
```

Comment: List slices are copies of the list themselves. id(A) != id(A[0:m])

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your slices - `A[0:m]`, etc. These don't create a view into the original list, but rather create new lists.

You could use numpy arrays as described [at the bottom of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131563/765210), or use the return values of your recursive calls in order to construct a new list to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

1.- You are sending copies of your original array to recursion and not just parts of the original array. 
2.- Although you will send parts of original array, [pseudocode Stooge Sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort) doesn't work with parts of array, just indexes.

```
def StoogeSort(L, i, j):
    if L[i] > L[j]: #<-- always switching elements (not just for n=2)
        L[j],L[i]=L[i],L[j]  
    if (j - i + 1) > 2:
        t = int((j - i + 1) / 3)
        StoogeSort(L, i, j-t)  #<-- here, sending indexes.
        StoogeSort(L, i+t,j)
        StoogeSort(L, i, j-t)
    return L

>>> L = [7,8,9,5,6,4,2,1]
>>> StoogeSort(L, 0, len(L)-1)
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```