# python using random.shuffle() on only part of a list

Tags: python, random

I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm in python. I have a list of 100 objects, sorted, and I need to access the top 30 plus 20 random others. My method is:

```
random.shuffle(list[30:])  #keep top 30, shuffle the rest
for x in range (50):
    list[x].do_stuff
```

This doesn't work, the list is unchanged. Is my syntax wrong or is my entire method impossible?
thanks

Comment: So out of a sorted list, you want to build a new one, with the top 30 and 20 randomly selected elements, right?

Comment: Please include the actual code you used.

Comment: You could have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy

Comment: `list[30:]` creates a _new list_, which you then shuffle, it doesn't alter the existing list at all.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to do this

```py
your_sliced_list = a[30:]
random.shuffle(your_sliced_list)
a[30:] = your_sliced_list
```

`list` is a python builtin so you shouldn't use it as a variable name as it overwrites the builtin, thats why in the code I have used `a` instead of `list`.

The reason why your code wasn't working was that when you slice the list it creates a new list which isn't assigned to a variable and `random.shuffle` shuffles that.