# Space complexity of slicing a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the space complexity of splicing list in python if we are using it for calculating sum? and we are not assigning a list to anything.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
sum_except_first = sum(a[1:])
```

Comment: It's O(n), with n being the length of your list

Comment: But we are not assigning a list to anything just using it for sum?

Comment: You assign it to the parameter you pass into `sum`

Comment: You're still creating it, even if you don't assign it to any variable

Comment: Space and time complexity do not care if you actually use the thing you loop over or create as long as you loop or create it counts. It is up to you to not create / loop unnecessary things. Here obviously it is necessary to create the slice and therefore it counts, what you do with the slice is irrelevant.

Comment: To reduce the space I can take sum(a) and subtract it from first element to get remaining sum right so then space wont be used?

Comment: `sum(a) - a[0]` would for example have better space complexity. A for loop that starts at index 1 instead of 0 would also perform better.

Comment: So using sum(a)-a[0] will do it in constant space right?

Comment: Probably, not sure how `sum` is implemented but I would hope it is smart.

Comment: What if we do not want to consider a in space considering it is a leetcode problem where a is passed as param and that is not included in space complexity calculation

Comment: Sum if inbuilt python function that I am using

Comment: it's linear. whether or not you assign the resulting list to a variable is irrelevant, it is still created

Comment: If `a` is the input then you can compute its sum in constant space, yes.

Comment: @luk2302 so even if we use splicing and a is the input it is constant space right?

Comment: the question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slicing a list in Python without generating a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy)

Comment: I saw the link but even if the reference of element is stored the sliced list new memory would be required as if we update the sliced list main list is not updated right?

Comment: Then it depends on your definition and the way you measure it - overall you could argue it takes 2n space, one n for the input, one n for the slice, therefore O(n). Or just one n for the slice if you disregard the input. If you then optimize the slice away you end up either with one n (still O(n)) or zero n (would be O(1))

Comment: Yup. If you dont consider input slice would be still O(n) if I remove slice and do sum(a)-firstelem then it would be constant