# creation of local variable

Tags: python, local

What is the difference between

```
def delete_head1(t):
    #t[:] = t[1:]
    t = t[1:]
```

and

```
def delete_head2(t):
    t[:] = t[1:]
    #t = t[1:]
```

Why does the second one modify the input but not the first? That is, if I do

```
k=[1,2,3]
delete_head1(k)
print(k)
```

versus

```
k=[1,2,3]
delete_head2(k)
print(k)
```

The results are different.
As I understand, the first one, in its body, creates and refers to a local variable `t`. Why isn't the second one also referring to a local variable t?

If in the body of the function I have:

```
t = t[1:]
```

the interpreter recognizes the second `t` (the one after the equals sign) but not the first `t` (the one before the equals sign)?

But this is not the case if I write

```
t[:] = t[1:]
```

In this last statement it recognizes both `t`? What is the guiding principle here for Python?

Comment: If you do not edit your post then both functions give the same output which is an error.

Comment: `t[:] = t[1:]` creates a shallow copy

Comment: why doesn't t=t[1:] create a shallow copy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slicing a list in Python without generating a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy)

Comment: Roganjosh, the link you sent may be good. The short answer is: Slicing lists does not generate copies of the objects in the list; it just copies the references to them. But what is the principle? Are there other cases other than slicing that don't generate copies? Seems a bit ad hoc.

Comment: You've missed the point. A shallow copy would also give references to the items in the list, but the list itself is a different object. In this case, you're still referring to the same list itself - the outer container, unless you take the shallow copy

Comment: [This](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) may help in the general case, but I'm not sure it covers this case

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623383/1964317

Comment: `t[1:]` creates a shallow copy (of part of the list). The assignment does not (or at least, only as an implementation detail). `t[:] = ...`, rather, *transfers* values from some iterable *into* the current list `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment statements behave differently depending on what the target it. You are correct that assignment to a name in a function create a local variable, but only one of your examples actually assigns to a *name*.

---

When the target is a simple name,

```
t = ...
```

this simply makes `t` refer to whatever object `...` produces, and leaves the old value of `t` with one less reference.

---

When the target is a *slice*,

```
t[:] = ...
```

this is really syntactic sugar for

```
t = t.__setitem__(slice(None, None, None), ...)
```

`t` *might* refer to a new object afterwards, depending on what `t.__setitem__` returns. But *usually*, this method returns the same object, and as a *side effect* alters the object in some way.

For lists, `t[:] = some_list` is basically equivalent to

```
t.clear()
t.extend(some_list)
```

`t` refers to the same list before and after, but the *contents* of that list change.

The full details of the *syntax* are in section 7.2, [Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) of the language documentation. The semantics of `list.__setitem__` in particular aren't spelled out in great detail, but can be inferred from the description of the syntax and the description of [`s[i:j:k] = t`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).