# Why does ` arr[n:].extend(arr[:n]) ` in the 1st example code print the original arr?

Tags: python

1st Example

```py
def LShift(arr,n):
    arr[n:].extend(arr[:n])  # changes arr itself
    print (arr)
    
arr = [10,20,54,5656,30,40,12,11]
LShift(arr,2)
```

Output `[10,20,54,5656,30,40,12,11]` I do not know why the original array is printed. Place holders are required to get the desired result.

```py
def LShift(arr, n):
    a1 = arr[n:]
    a2 = arr[:n]
    a1.extend(a2)
    arr = a1
    print(arr)


arr = [10, 20, 54, 5656, 30, 40, 12, 11]
LShift(arr, 2)
```

will work. Output=`[54, 5656, 30, 40, 12, 11, 10, 20]`

Comment: Slicing [generates a new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy), to wich you append the items and then throw that new list away in your first example. The original list isn't affetced at all.

Comment: By the way `arr = a1` doesn't change value of array that was passed into `LShift`, try to `print(arr)` after calling `LShift(arr, 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here in `arr[n:].extend(arr[:n])  # changes arr itself`
you are first taking a sliced list ie arr[n:] and on top of that you are extending this new list.

this sliced list ie `arr[:n]` is not same as `arr` it is new one and doesn't do modify the orignal list and create a new one and after that you are extending this list with new sublist, generating alltogether a new list which is not orignal `arr` one.

because of this you are getting this result

Comment: That makes sense to me. I watched Thonny process `arr[n:].extend(arr[:n])`. Thonny showed each list `[54, 5656, 30, 40, 12, 11].extend([10, 20])` which exists briefly in memory.

Comment: yes, since your just modifying new list, it wont affect orignal one and giving you that output

Answer (score 0):

In your first example didn't create a new list or update but returns a view of the original list. So, your arr will be the same with your original array. To avoid this u can change that part to `arr[n:].extend(arr[:n])` to this `arr = arr[n:] + arr[:n]`. So your final code will be like.

```
def LShift(arr, n):
    arr = arr[n:] + arr[:n]
    print(arr)
    return arr

arr = [10, 20, 54, 5656, 30, 40, 12, 11]
res = LShift(arr, 2)
print(res)
```

Comment: This answer shows an alternative to the second code example in the question. However, it did not help me understand why the first code example did not work, so I did not accept it as the best answer.

Comment: I explained in first sentence which is that  **In your first example didn't create a new list or update but shows a view of the original list.So, simply you don't return your array but only show your arr.** @Carl_M