# For Loop for n iterations-Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a simple for loop in a Python script:

```
for filename in filenames:
    outline = getinfo(filename)
    outfile.write(outline)
```

This for loop is part of a larger script that extracts data from HTML pages. I have nearly 6GB of HTML pages and want to do some test runs before I try it on all of them.

How can I make the loop break after a set number of iterations (lets say 100)?

Comment: Use a counter and break if that counter is equal to 100.

Comment: This should be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688079 but I ran out of close votes today.

Answer (score 12):

```
for filename in filenames[:100]:
    outline= getinfo(filename)
    outfile.write(outline)
```

The list slice `filenames[:100]` will truncate the list of file names to just the first 100 elements.

Comment: For a general iterator (not necessarily a list): `for filename in itertools.islice(filenames, 100):`.

Comment: @chepner Is that necessary also in Python 3?

Comment: Yes; you can't use slice syntax with arbitrary iterators.

Answer (score 9):

Keep a counter for your for loop.  When your counter reaches, 100, break

```
counter = 0
for filename in filenames:
    if counter == 100:
        break
    outline= getinfo(filename)
    outfile.write(outline)
    counter += 1
```

Comment: The preferred way to keep a counter is to do `for (counter, filename) in enumerate(filenames)`.

Answer (score 2):

I like @kqr's answer, but just another approach to consider, instead of taking the first 100,  you could take a random `n` many instead:

```
from random import sample
for filename in sample(filenames, 10):
    # pass
```

Comment: I would argue this is the better solution as long as it doesn't have any terrible performance issues.

Comment: @kqr the main issue I would be worried about is reproduce-ability.... So maybe the compromise is to take 1 in n instead, which could be done nicely with slicing as shown in your answer... And still be more useful for testing...

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, but discarded since it would probably have similar performance to taking a random sample. I didn't think about testability, but you are indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in function [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), available in both Python 2 and 3.

```py
for idx,filename in enumerate(filenames):
    if idx == 100:
        break
    outline= getinfo(filename)
    outfile.write(outline)
```

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522578/10600556).